# How to read XML CDATA with SAS

Tags: xml, import, sas, cdata

I have XML files containing multidimensional arrays of numeric data and I need to read them into SAS.

To make files smaller, the format has been specified so that the data are stored in an one-dimensional CDATA array.

To get an idea of the structure of the files, consider something like this:

```
<!-- Metadata -->
<table name=foo>
<axis id=axis1 name=x>
  <value>1</value>
  ...
</axis>
<axis id=axis2>
  ...   
</axis>
<!-- Data -->
<data>
  <![CDATA[
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
  ]]>
</data>
```

That is, the axes are defined in metadata and the values are stored in the order specified by the order of the axes.

It's easy to set up an XMLMap to read the metadata, but I have no idea how to get to the CDATA. Any suggestions?